# Pass custom data to PrivateRoute component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am new in ReactJS and starting my first app with React. I've been watching videos and going through various tutorials and finally managed to scaffold my first ReactRedux app with Login.

I've used [AuthWorkflow](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) example of ReactTraining website. There they used a `PrivateRoute` component to secure protected routes. I've implemented it and its working.

**Problem:**
Now I can't send any custom data or like user data to protected route. How can I sent it?

**Code**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 1. Click the public page
// 2. Click the protected page
// 3. Log in
// 4. Click the back button, note the URL each time

const AuthExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <AuthButton />
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/public">Public Page</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Route path="/public" component={Public} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />

       // Here I want to pass the user data to protected component.
      <PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Protected} user={username:'ariful', email:'test@example.com'}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
    setTimeout(cb, 100); // fake async
  },
  signout(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    setTimeout(cb, 100);
  }
};

const AuthButton = withRouter(
  ({ history }) =>
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <p>
        Welcome!{" "}
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            fakeAuth.signout(() => history.push("/"));
          }}
        >
          Sign out
        </button>
      </p>
    ) : (
      <p>You are not logged in.</p>
    )
);

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);

const Public = () => <h3>Public</h3>;

// show the username here
const Protected = (props) => <h3>Protected Username: {props.user.username}</h3>;

class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirectToReferrer: false
  };

  login = () => {
    fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
      this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
    const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;

    if (redirectToReferrer) {
      return <Redirect to={from} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>You must log in to view the page at {from.pathname}</p>
        <button onClick={this.login}>Log in</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AuthExample;
```

How can I successfully send the user object to protected component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass on the `...rest` params that you pass to `PrivateRoute` on to the component, however not all of them need to react the component. You can destructure other params that are needed by React router

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, exact, strict, path, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    exact={exact}
    strict={strict}
    path={path}
    render={props =>
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} {...rest} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @ArifulHaque, Glad to have helped, Its was indeed a good question to work on

Answer (score 1):

See where the issue is:

```
<PrivateRoute 
   path="/protected" 
   component={Protected} 
   user={username:'ariful', email:'test@example.com'} />
```

Now inside `PrivateRoute` component, user object will get passed as props, it will be available in `rest` object, also `rest` will have the data that will be required for `Route`, so to make it more generic.

Instead of passing the user object always pass `data`, now rest will have the data required for Route and data will be the data passed to component, write it like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, data, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} {...data} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

Pass that data to `<Component {...data} {...props} />`

Comment: Upvote for explaining. Will try this approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

**PrivateRoute for functional component with react-redux hook**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => {
const isAuthenticated = useSelector((state)=>state.isAuthenticated)
  return (
    <Route
    {...rest}
render={props =>
  isAuthenticated === true ? (
    <Component {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  )
}
/>
)
}


export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing too fancy, just call a render function and pass some data into the component.

```
<PrivateRoute
 render = {() => 
  <Component
   data = {value}
  />}
 path = "/path"
/>
```